# Murderer in the house!

Tags: steganography, mystery

It was a dark and stormy night...

No wait, no it wasn't! It was a clear sunny day. When Brian had 3 of his old buddies from school over for a get together in Texas. They were all aged 35.

His friends were named Louis, Gus (or "Augustine") and Diana. Brian didn't know it, but this would be his last day on the face of the Earth.

Brian did however know the history behind his friends. He knew which one of them was a murderer. He had for years. He only considerered the possibility of him getting killed last minute.

He wrote the following letter:

> Dear whomever it may concern,
>
> This is very important. It's become the centre of my attention that I could die on this very day, 8/6/2015. I am leaving this message in hopes to tell you who it is but in all the current emotions I can't remember his name.
>   I apologise if this doesn't work out, but I'm trying my best. Be sure to analyse this letter very carefully. Now just in case I will be travelling to a new world, goodbye.

Using all the given information in this puzzle, what is the most accurate guess at the murderer you can possibly make?

Comment: Is the edit (his -> the) significant, or just a typo?

Comment: TFiOS? That looks like one...

Comment: @the4seasons What? I looked that up and got "The Fault in Our Stars" isn't that a movie? What are you talking about?

Comment: Read the book / watch the movie and you will know the character names. One of the main characters is called Augustus, also known as Gus, so I brought that up.

Comment: @the4seasons Oh cool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

> Gus (Augustine)

Reasons:

> Centre is misspelled to draw attention to it. Center fits as "Gus" is a nickname from Au**gus**tine and it is also the middle name of the namesake Augustine of Hippo (*Aurelius **Augustinus** Hipponensis*). 
> Second, the switch of month and day (today is 6/8/2015, as the OP states they are in Texas should use American date) points to **August** when corrected. 
> Then *can't remember **his** name* means it has to be Louis or Gus. 
> Also, though this may have nothing to do with it, I like *St. Augustine **New World** Gin*
> **Update**: Also *apologise* provide two possible clues: one it starts with a, ends with e, and is the same number of letters as Augustine and Augustine of Hippo is famous for an apology (here meaning reasoning for belief or reasoned defense of faith). 
> And I really just took *analyse* as a hint that you needed to analyze the miss-spellings.

Comment: "centre" is the correct spelling in most english-speaking countries. Only America (and I assume Canada) spell it "center".

Comment: @GlenO right, but OP stated the writer was from Texas - so assuming American spelling. Hence: "miss-spelled"

Comment: Also 'analyse' and 'apologise' (and maybe 'travelling') are non-standard in American English.

Comment: @JulianRosen I added my thoughts on *analyse* and *apologise* - I actually see both travelling and traveling so often that I didn't consider that one

Comment: @JGreenwell - sure, but the whole thing is full of non-American spellings and formats. The date refers to today in the D/M/YY format, and there are four words in the text that have different spellings inside and outside America, all of which have their non-American spellings. Perhaps they're meeting in Texas, Queensland (a town here in Australia)? Or maybe they're Britons living in America?

Comment: @GlenO Any of that could be true - I'm just assuming the Texas meeting is a meeting of Texans (or at least Americans) as that's part of how I came up with this answer. By noticing what I took as miss-spellings of words (or what an American writer would consider miss-spellings). Could easily be wrong, but thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: Great job :) ${}$

Comment: Also, not part of the puzzle, but still a nice bit of information, Augustine is a British name.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess here:

> The killer is Diana

Because:

> Brian "can't remember his name", because the killer is not a "he". So he has to "remember her name". Also two Dianas are born August 6.

Alternatively:

> Obviously Gus, as OP spend extra time describing him (giving both name and nickname). Also the month in the date of the letter is August.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the murderer is

> Louis

Because:

> Brian is informing Gus (as reference to the date (8(August)/6/2015). "...I could die on this very day, 8/6/2015. I am leaving this message in hopes to tell you ...".
> This means Brian is informing about the other male character (remember his name...) who is Louis.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I've slightly edited your answer to improve the readability, still I suggest you to further motivate your answer, as it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: @leoll2 "Motivate your answer" makes no sense. clarify would.